# Drawing on a image or texture to get a sense of RTS style minimap in Unity 5.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am looking for a step by step explanations on how to create an image that would be in the beginning a black square shape on a Canvas component.

Second of all I would look for a way to make the image pixels or spots on the image coloured white where the player has walked. I have no idea how is this accomplished. Texture2D and SetPixels are the topics I am currently looking into.

This would come to a camera that is a minimap displayer. It would the fog like in the RTS games often have like the Command & Conquer Tiberium Dawn for example.

Later edited and/or added:

I got with the code of this thread on another forum to a point where I can SetPixel to Color.Clear on Unity's start Event but don't know how to make it to work on Update or continuously. Color.Clear is used for the Black Layer or a Texture that is black so that it reveals the minimap (minimap camera) underneath while setting pixels. It draws a line on the Start()-event.

I had hoped it to clear the minimap when I walk with the player character. I don't know how to make the line continuous. I'm still a little bit on the process of figuring this one out. If you have tips on this problem, you can share them with me if you like.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/244417/create-line-on-a-texture.html

Comment: **I am looking for a step by step explanations..**. Any link that you would like to share?

Comment: At the moment there is no link, sorry, might be at some point. I have to take some time to think about this.

Comment: I wish I could share a link. I have to think about it more. I am in a point of this tutorial where the author has written: "now renders Minimap Camera image in it". So the tutorial is here: http://blog.theknightsofunity.com/implementing-minimap-unity/

Comment: I followed the tutorial to get a square minimap camera. It now functions to some extent when I made the minimap camera's size so large it shows the level objects all at once. There ain't too many objects.

Answer (score 1):

Very broad description of how I would implement it:

1. Create a separate orthogonal camera looking from upside down on the map. This will be a minimap camera. Now it just renders the same world you already see. If I would be doing a rough prototype, it would be enough.
2. Make all existing renderers render only into the original camera, either thorugh rendering or game object layers. Now minimap camera shows nothing.
3. For all game objects you want in the minimap, create child objects with renderers that will only appear in the minimap camera. Now minimap sees these objects only; you probably want to use sprite renderers with special icons on them.
4. Render minimap camera in the appropariate place on the screen. Alternatively, render it to a texture and use texture in RawImage inside the UI system.

It's not the best solution, but it's fast to implement, and is good enough for a lot of use cases.

Comment: I really like this solution. Can you say how you define which camera render which objects? With layers?

Comment: I see it now - Culling mask I quess?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all suggestions. I try to think about the minimap camera more from these perspectives.

Comment: I think I'll manage the problem on my own from here. Thanks again. I might share the results.